# Primer Choice Input

Tags: walls, floor, primer

We are skim-coating our walls and ceiling to fill in texturing. We bought a fixer upper and our best option was to skim coat. We are looking at the water-based B-I-N 123 and Kilz as our two primer options because we also want to use the same primer on our subfloors (chipboard) before we put new flooring down. Previous owners left urine-soaked, and unknown stain and odor-filled carpets. We've also had our dogs decide to do their business where they smell previous smells.

I would like to receive a consensus from your communal wisdom as to which primer you prefer for such work.

TIA

Comment: I would replace the stained / damaged subfloor - it will continue to smell and the dogs will still "find" it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both primers you suggest will work about the same. Primers are designed to be sticky, providing a bond between walls and paint. If the floors are impregnated with urine, dogs will continue to be triggered by the smell. Other than replacing the subfloor -- a major job -- I would apply an enzymatic treatment to the subfloor to try destroy as much urine that might be hiding in the cracks, etc., then add a layer of sheet plastic between the subfloor and the floor covering.

Comment: Thank you cheery.beach7701 and @SolarMike. This is good information. I was under the impression that these primers would block the smell. Now we know it won't work, and we'll get what we need to make sure there are no more smells for the dogs to detect.